# Is it possible to create a GTM variable that will store the first referral made if the same GTM is installed on all cross-referred domains?

Tags: javascript, google-analytics, google-tag-manager

Let's say a click on a link on the website A occurs and it leads the user to the website B and the referral on the B would be A. However, if a user clicks on another link in B, then the referral would become B.

If the same GTM is installed on all of the domains, is it possible to store the first referral to B in a variable? So that even if a user clicks on an another link in B, I would still be able to reference the referral variable that was generated in the transition from A to B.

I hope I have explained it well enough. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

I think you meant A and not B in the second paragraph.

But regardless, it's fairly trivial to do by using a custom HTML tag that would store the referrer value in a cookie on each page load but only when it isn't contained by the current `document.location.href`. Alternatively, you can use a template instead of a tag, but that's a complication. A CJS var will work, but we typically avoid writing with vars.

Then you just use whatever's in the cookie.

The cookie, however, as any local storage, can only be shared within one TLD. Sharing it across multiple TLDs will be a more complex task, yet still possible. Say by migrating this or a similar logic to the backend rather than GTM.

Comment: What I meant was, if a user goes from A > B > C and they are different domains with the same GTM, can I keep the referrer variable from A > B even when user is in website C? Maybe it is the same thing you described, I'll just have to take a look

Comment: I actually don't understand how this is done, could you please explain it like I am 5 years old?

Comment: yes, so theoretically, it's possible, but not with conventional methods. You will have to build some sort of backend communication or a third-party cookie to store the referrer. This goes into deeper: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12514222/how-i-can-set-third-party-cookie An alternative would be appending the data you want to pass to the url, which looks pretty bad. It would be a lot easier if you had subdomains linking, rather than domains. It can also be fixed by dedicating a session-level dimension in GA UA, but not in GA4 since they removed it in GA4...